# Javascript value is undefined, function runs after value is assigned

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I load my variable "vSave" with data. This is where Javascript confuses me. It seems the way I wrote this vSave is undefined when it is returned but I know the response.on('end') runs and has the data I am looking for. I just don't know how to get it returned to my router so I can use it on my client side.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var config = require('../config_bartapi');
var http = require('http');
var vTemp; // [DEBUG]
var vSave; // [DEBUG]
// Real Time Departure from a given station
router.route('/departTimeStation')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        var vParsed = '';
        vCmd = 'etd';
        vOrig = req.query.vOriginStation;
        vDir = 'n'; // [NOTE] - 'n' or 's', north or south, OPTIONAL
        vPlat = 1; // [NOTE] - 1 to 4, number of platform, OPTIONAL

        var xoptions = {
            host: 'api.bart.gov',
            path: '/api/etd.aspx?cmd=' + vCmd + '&orig=' + vOrig + '&key=' + config.bart.client
        };

        var xcallback = function(response) {
            response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                vParsed += chunk;
            });
            response.on('end', function() {
                parseString(vParsed, function(err, result) {
                    vSave = JSON.stringify(result.root.station);
                });
            });
        };
        var vTestHttp = http.request(xoptions, xcallback).end();
        return res.send (vSave);
    });
// list all BART stations
router.route('/listAllStations')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        var vParsed = '';
        vCmd = 'stns';
        var options = {
            host: 'api.bart.gov',
            path: '/api/stn.aspx?cmd=' + vCmd + '&key=' + config.bart.client
        };
        var callback = function(response) {
            response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                vParsed += chunk;
            });

            response.on('end', function() {
                parseString(vParsed, function(err, result) {
                    vTemp = result.root.stations[0].station;
                });
            });
        };
        var vTestHttp2 = http.request(options, callback).end();
        return res.send (vTemp)
    });
module.exports = router;
```

Thanks for your help. It seems like an easy concept but I just can't seem to get it.

I had to edit. This is the full bit of code. I originally posted only the one module. Sorry for the extreme edit.

Comment: You can't return vSave at that point, as the callback has not been executed yet. It will execute later, asynchronously.

Comment: How would I wait for the response? It isn't working but I am not sure how to modify it in a way that does work. The 'listAllStations' route works every time but the 'departTimeStation' never works. It seems having more than one http.request is messing me up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to send it in the callback you pass to parseString() function.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I will keep testing it but the first run was beautiful. I will accept this as the answer shortly. Stack is making me wait 5 minutes to accept answers